# how do resolve firebase permission denied error on android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

The app keeps hanging where the app is trying to access the firebase database.
Here is the code where the app is trying to access the database.

```
     mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        Log.d("getUid()", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final AlertDialog a = Utiles.createLoadingDialog(getActivity(), "Loading..");
        databaseReference.child("bibles").orderByChild("likecount").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                bList.clear();
                bList2.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot i : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Bible b = i.getValue(Bible.class);
                    // System.out.println("TTTTT" + b.toString());


                    b.setKey(i.getKey());
                    if (b.getCategory().equals(value)) {
                        if (b.getIsChecked().get(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()) == null) {
                            bList2.add(b);

                            // Log.d("TAG", bList2.toString());
                            continue;
                        }

                        bList.add(b);
                    }
                }
```

My app shows it keeps loading. and the error log says

E/fragment1: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: Permission denied

security rule:

```
{
  "rules": { 
        "bibles":{
            ".read": "auth!=null",
        ".write": "auth!=null"  
                            }
                    }
  
}
```

and when I close my app and reopen it, then it can access the database so it runs perfectly and it creates a new authentication uid on my dashboard.

When I look at my code where it creates current users.
Here is the code. As you can see in the code below, there is a log called "!!!!mCurrentUser". This log shouldn't be printed out when the app is freshly installed.
but after I delete the app and reinstall it, somehow, the app prints out "!!!!mCurrentUser". So I am guessing somehow the firebase database system recognizes my phone as current user even if I delete the app. Does anyone have some idea on this? Thank you in advance.

```
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (mCurrentUser == null) {
        Log.d("UserNull", "test");
        mAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d("signIn", "test");
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdClosed() {
                                //TODO: Intent
                                //
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);


                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        //TODO: Intent
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);



                    }

                } else {
                    Log.d("authentication failed", "failed");
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        Log.d("!!!!mCurrentUser", String.valueOf(mCurrentUser.getUid()));
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdClosed() {
                            //TODO: Intent
                            //
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);


                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    //TODO: Intent
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);



                }

            }
        }, 1000);

    }
}
```

Comment: Uninstalling the app should wipe out any user credentials.

Comment: Thank you for your response. but why do I get this log "!!!!mCurrentUser" even after re-installing the app? Do you have any idea on this...?

Comment: No, there's not enough code here to tell. current user will always be null on a fresh install.  Anything else doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yeah, I also think that current user will always be null on a fresh install. but I don't know why the log print out like this. I edited the post to show where the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is happening because of firebase permissions , so i'd suggest you take a look at this link for more details :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart

Comment: Thank you for your response but I edited my post. I set my rule for only authenticated user to access database.